# Terence Tao Analysis 1 Exercise 3.4.1

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Exercise 3.4.1. Let $f : X → Y$ be a bijective function, and let $f^{−1}: Y → X$
be its inverse. Let $V$ be any subset of $Y$ . Prove that the forward image of $V$
under $f^{−1}$ is the same set as the inverse image of $V$ under $f$; thus the fact that
both sets are denoted by $f^{−1}(V)$ will not lead to any inconsistency.

Do I get it right that I have to prove $f^{-1} \circ f (V) = f \circ f^{-1}(V) $?
If so, what does $f (V) $ is equal to? $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$, but $V$ is a subset of $Y$.
My other idea is that I have to prove $f^{-1} \circ f (S) = f \circ f^{-1}(V) $, but it is not true, because on the left side is $S$ and on the right is $V$. So could anyone please explain what I have to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you have to prove is that, for each subset $V$ of $Y$, the sets:

- $\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in V\}$ (the inverse image of $V$ under $f$);
- $\left\{f^{-1}(v)\,\middle|\,v\in V\right\}$ (the forward image of $V$ under $f^{-1}$)

are equal.

Comment: Do I get it right that forward image of subset $B$ of codomain $Y$ is $B$ itself? Then what does inverse image of subset $S$ of domain $X$ is equal to?

Comment: Imagine that $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint. Then how can possibly the forward image of $B$ be $B$ itself? Note that $B\subset Y$, whereas its forward image is a subset of $X$.

Comment: What forward image of subset of $X$ is equal to?

Comment: By definition, if $V$ is that subset, then it is equal to $\left\{f^{-1}(v)\,\middle|\,v\in V\right\}$.

Comment: That makes no sense. Since we are dealing here with a function $f$ from $X$ into $Y$, it only makes sense to talk about inverse images of subsets of $Y$.

Comment: Is forward image of $V$ equal to forward image of corresponding subset of $X$?

Comment: Are we talking about the forward image of $V$ with respect to $f^{-1}$. And what is the “corresponding subset of $X$”?

Comment: $S := $ {$s=x∈X | f(x)∈V$}

Comment: *If* we are talking about the forward image with respect to $f^{-1}$, then the question makes no sense, since $S$ is a subset of $X$ rather than a subset of $Y$.

Comment: I had a go at answering this question - with additional discussion which I hope is helpful to readers. Since I am self-teaching, I may have made errors, so appreciate feedback. https://analysis-solutions.blogspot.com/2024/01/tao-analysis-i-341.html